# Pycoin: How to sign SegWit transaction via Pycoin?

Tags: segregated-witness, python, utxo, pycoin

My target is to make transaction with unspent transaction outputs(UTXOS).
The information of UTXOs is as follow.

```
[   
  {
    "pt_idx": 0,
    "subaccount": 37,
    "ga_asset_id": 1,
    "value": "92343",
    "block_height": 1288714,
    "txhash": "9e2d2d56632b609e9b5d0a1990cf0ffbd9865cec558b68ed106df352fd89cfb1",
    "pointer": 1083,
    "script_type": 14   
  },
  {
    "pt_idx": 1,
    "subaccount": 37,
    "ga_asset_id": 1,
    "value": "9961066",
    "block_height": 1288718,
    "txhash": "b0e37f463aba4e3abb078eb77c472b29621cfdd17ed83ae41122b0b95df5e518",
    "pointer": 1096,
    "script_type": 14   
  },
  {
    "pt_idx": 1,
    "subaccount": 37,
    "ga_asset_id": 1,
    "value": "315595",
    "block_height": 1288721,
    "txhash": "b062efcab010d436ca2f6bed0dc61b90d8cbced756e1ed7cc7593cac30d87326",
    "pointer": 1099,
    "script_type": 14   
  },
  {
    "pt_idx": 1,
    "subaccount": 37,
    "ga_asset_id": 1,
    "value": "1872759",
    "block_height": 1288716,
    "txhash": "f88cfdb328f9d298b0ff8a641198d3e63ea7efaf6f98f5692ba3f88a03a73c2b",
    "pointer": 1088,
    "script_type": 14   }
]
```

From these I made transaction using pycoin library.
By the way, it is difficult to sign a SegWit transaction.
If anyone knows about this, please tell me.

Comment: What the pycoin version ?

Comment: pycoin 0.80.If you have solution, Pls tell me.

Comment: @Mickey102644 Can you paste the (unsigned) transaction you made with Pycoin?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user doesn't show any trace of experiment or trial-and-error whatsoever, essentially asking us to write code for them.

Answer (score 0):

For compatible segwit transactions, it is basically using p2sh transactions.
For `pycoin` specifically, you need to provide `p2sh_lookup` dict when sign the p2sh transaction.
I have a [sample](https://github.com/xuanzhui/cryptocoin-py/blob/master/btc_sample.py) for bitcoin offline/paper transaction if you would like to check, the method `spend_sh_fund` may suit your need.

Comment: What about native segwit? Is there library to sign those?